# PayPal Express Checkout - hide shipping address

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using PayPal Express Checkout (Payflow) on my store. My checkout journey looks like:

1. Shopping Basket
2. Delivery Address and Option
3. Payment Option (Paypal or card)

On stage 3, if the user chooses Paypal i need to hide viewing and being able to change the shipping address within Paypal as i already define them a step before.

My request is like so when i redirect my page to paypal:

```
$paypal_query_array = array(
    'USER'       => $user,
    'VENDOR'     => $vendor,
    'PARTNER'    => $partner,
    'PWD'        => $password,
    'TENDER'     => 'P',
    'TRXTYPE'    => 'S', 
    'ACTION'     => 'S',
    'AMT'        => $_SESSION['cost'],
    'CURRENCY'   => $currency,
    'CANCELURL'  => $cancel_url,
    'RETURNURL'  => $return_url,
    'INVNUM'     => $_SESSION['invoice'],
    'ORDERDESC'  => $description,
    'NOSHIPPING' => 1,
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 0
);

foreach ($paypal_query_array as $key => $value) {
    $paypal_query[]= $key.'['.strlen($value).']='.$value;
}

$paypal_query=implode('&', $paypal_query);
$nvpArray = fetch_data($unique_id, $submiturl, $paypal_query);

if($nvpArray['RESPMSG']=='Approved') {
    $payPalURL = $PayPalURL.urldecode($nvpArray["TOKEN"]);
    header('Location: '.$payPalURL);
}
```

I assumed that `NOSHIPPING` and `ADDOVERRIDE` would allow this but i still get a shipping address and ability to change on the paypal page.

Answer (score 1):

NOSHIPPING will completely remove shipping altogether.  ADDROVERRIDE would use whatever address you pass in the SetExpressCheckout request and not allow the buyer to change it.

So it sounds like ADDROVERRIDE is what you're wanting, but you're not passing any address in the request, so I'm a little confused by that.

Comment: Ideally `NOSHIPPING` is what i want as i don't want to show any shipping within paypal. I tried adding the `ADDROVERRIDE` as well just to see if that  helped. I have tried both of them, either of them on their own (passing shipping name, address etc) if `ADDROVERRIDE` but that nevers work either

Comment: So you're saying that with NOSHIPPING set it's still letting the person choose a shipping address during checkout?  That would be very odd, and it's not something I'm able to reproduce in my testing.